# Remove help button from excel data validation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto, excel-2007

I want to remove Help button from data validation.
In excel 2003 data validation this button is not there but now I want to remove this from excel 2007 data validation error.
Please don't ask why you want to remove help button.

my project type is excel template of visual studio 2008.

[image: SS of data validation error of excel 2007]

**EDIT**

Is there any other way to accomplish this thing apart from Worksheet_Change? I think it might decrease performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove the Help button if you are using the built in Data Validation. You would be well advised to simply live with the help button as the only known work-around will be time consuming to recreate Excel's built-in functionality.

You'll need to make a custom msgbox that listens for the Worksheet Change and checks the value. Here's a VBA example [basically taken from here](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/excel-error-alert-window-on-data-validation#post-270371):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
dim msg as string
dim Style as string
dim Title as string
dim Response as long
'Update Cells to be the actuall range you want to validate
If Intersect(Target, Cells(1, 2)) Then
    If Cells(1, 2).Value <> "whatever" Then
        msg = "Value must be LT 1"
        Style = vbRetryCancel + vbCritical
        Title = "Mt Error"
        Response = MsgBox(msg, Style, Title)
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited a question, can you please check. please give me solution according to that.

Comment: @TusharChhabhaiya: The solution is in the shared link - do not do it. There are many things that Excel does behind the scenes that is not possible/feasible to replicate via the Excel object library.